# Checkbox inline with text - JS issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, alignment

I'm currently learning how to program and have been stuck trying to finish the design of a form. I've looked at all previous questions, but none of the solutions seems to work :S. Below are the two things I want to fix:

1. Change the text color and border of the dropdown menu.
2. Align the checkbox and label so they are on the same line.

The code can be seen here: http://codepen.io/jbender90/pen/rebbEB

**Here is my current setup for the checkbox and label:**

```
<div id="menu">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" style="width: 100%;">

#menu{
    font-family: montserrat, arial, verdana;
    font-size:14px;
    border: #2C3E50;
    color:#2C3E50;
    text-align: left;
    height: 20px;
}
```

**Here is my current setup for the checkbox and label:**

```
<div class="inline-field">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <label for="checkbox">Remember me</label>
</div>

.inline-field input,
.inline-field label {
    display: inline-block !important;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom: 0; /* I added this after I posted my reply */
    vertical-align: middle; /* Fixes any weird issues in Firefox and IE */
    z-index:1;
}
```

Any advice would be welcomed with open arms!

Cheers,

Johan

Answer (score 0):

To do #1 you just have to target the drop down's classes to modify the properties so for the drop down border color and text you would have these two selector classes:

```
.select2-dropdown {
  border-color: yellow;
}

.select2-results__option {
  color: red;
}
```

This might not work in your code pen because you've included the select 2 css again inside the body which would override whatever you define in your style.css.

As for #2 there seems to be something setting the checkbox's width to be 100% thus pushing down the label. Another change I made was to wrap the input in the label. The html would look like this:

```
<label for="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox"> This text should be aligned with the checkbox</label>
```

To override the width:

```
#msform input {
  width: auto;
}
```

Here's the working example.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGMqLv